# Get Element from dynamic class name in Vue js

Tags: javascript, class, vue.js, getelementsbyclassname

```
<v-data-table
:headers="menuheaders"
//this menus from api response
    :items="menus"
        item-key="usersmenu_menuid"
        items-per-page="1000"
        hide-default-footer=""
        class="elevation-1"
        >
            <template v-slot:item.usersmenu_read="{ item }">
                <v-checkbox :class="`read${item.usersmenu_read}`" :value="item.usersmenu_read === 1 ? true : false "></v-checkbox>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:item.usersmenu_edit="{ item }">
                <v-checkbox :class="`edit${item.usersmenu_edit}`" :value="item.usersmenu_edit === 1 ? true : false "></v-checkbox>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:item.usersmenu_add="{ item }">
                <v-checkbox :class="`add${item.usersmenu_add}`" :value="item.usersmenu_add === 1 ? true : false "></v-checkbox>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:item.usersmenu_delete="{ item }">
                <v-checkbox :class="`delete${item.usersmenu_delete}`" :value="item.usersmenu_delete === 1 ? true : false "></v-checkbox>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
```

Hi all, i have problem with this code, i want to getElementByClassName

```
let read =  document.getElementsByClassName('read${usersmenu_read}')
```

But i dont know what i must fill in the flag.

```
let read =  document.getElementsByClassName(In this flag, What should i fill ?)
```

Please give me some explanation. Thanks for you all

Comment: You mean in `${usersmenu_read}`?

Comment: yeah, i want get element from v-checbox by class  name, but i dont know how to get it with getElementByClassName( i dont know what should i fill in here)

Comment: ```:class="`read${item.usersmenu_read}`"```  this gives ```class="read_and_here_item."``` and if you want get it ```document.getElementsByClassName(`read${usersmenu_read}`)``` you can use this. But usersmenu_read variable must be the same on v-checkbox class binding name. Add more code to understand the existing logic.

Comment: can you share your whole page component please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use `$refs` in VueJS instead of using `getElementsByClassName`. Follow this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

```
 <v-checkbox :class="`read${item.usersmenu_read}`" ref="readCheckbox" :value="item.usersmenu_read === 1 ? true : false "></v-checkbox>

// and use it in the component
this.$refs.readCheckbox
```

**Update**: for multiple checkbox
You can assign a ref to `v-data-table` instead directly in `v-checkbox`, and get all check box in DOM by use [Vue $refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs) same above.
If you want to use `getElementsByClass`, you can give the checkboxes with a same name that not depend on menus data, say it's "menu-checkbox". Your checkbox will be:

```
<v-checkbox class="menu-checkbox" :class="`read${item.usersmenu_read}`" :value="item.usersmenu_read === 1 ? true : false "></v-checkbox>
// same for edit/add/delete
```

Now you can retrieve all checkboxes by:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('menu-checkbox')
```

Comment: i have try it, and works but how to get multiples data (like fill in array or slice)?

Comment: @izzy45 I edited the answer for getting multiple checkboxes